# jQuery each in each function

Tags: jquery

I need some help/guide from you guys how can i get the data in the json result. How do i get the data from the product_quotas1 & product_quotas2?
I'm be grateful if someone can help or guide me to solve this.

```js
var myArrayNeed = {
  "3": {
    "id": "3",
    "state": "1",
    "charity_id": "3",
    "unmet_quotas": {
      "product_quotas1": {
        "product_id": "134",
        "quota": "32",
        "remaining_quota": "32",
        "progress": 0,
        "vegetarian": "0"
      },
      "product_quotas2": {
        "product_id": "153",
        "quota": "12",
        "remaining_quota": "12",
        "progress": 0,
        "vegetarian": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
jQuery.each(myArrayNeed, function(index, value) {
  //console.log("index :" + index + "value :" + value);
  jQuery.each(value, function(subindex, subvalue) {
    // console.log("index :" + subindex + "value :" + subvalue);
    var unmet_quotas = value.unmet_quotas;
    //console.log('Unmet Quota : ' + unmet_quotas);
    jQuery.each(unmet_quotas, function(subsubindex, subsubvalue) {
      console.log("index :" , subsubindex , "value :" , subsubvalue);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where to get value explain..?

Comment: I need to get the value of remaining_quota for each of product and stored in variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With slight adjustment to your code

```js
var myArrayNeed={
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "state": "1",
        "charity_id": "3",
        "unmet_quotas": {
            "product_quotas1": {
                "product_id": "134",
                "quota": "32",
                "remaining_quota": "32",
                "progress": 0,
                "vegetarian": "0"
            },
            "product_quotas2": {
                "product_id": "153",
                "quota": "12",
                "remaining_quota": "12",
                "progress": 0,
                "vegetarian": "1"
            }
          }
        }
    }
    jQuery.each(myArrayNeed, function(index, value) {

  jQuery.each(value.unmet_quotas, function(subindex, subvalue) {
 console.log(subvalue);
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The first `each` will iterate through your "Object" properties which is only one property for this example `3` the second `each` will iterate through the properties of `unmet_quotas` which are the objects that you want

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var myArrayNeed = {
  "3": {
    "id": "3",
    "state": "1",
    "charity_id": "3",
    "unmet_quotas": {
      "product_quotas1": {
        "product_id": "134",
        "quota": "32",
        "remaining_quota": "32",
        "progress": 0,
        "vegetarian": "0"
      },
      "product_quotas2": {
        "product_id": "153",
        "quota": "12",
        "remaining_quota": "12",
        "progress": 0,
        "vegetarian": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
//console.log(myArrayNeed);
jQuery.each(myArrayNeed, function(index, value) {
  jQuery.each(value.unmet_quotas, function(subindex, subvalue) {
    jQuery.each(subvalue, function(subsubindex, subsubvalue) {
      if (subsubindex == 'remaining_quota') {
        console.log("index :", subsubindex, "value :", subsubvalue);
        var remaining_quota = subsubvalue;
        alert(remaining_quota);
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```